# Rails: Is fields_for necessary for nested forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just finished making my first nested form and found that most of the trouble I had in getting it to work was me trying to avoid the "fields_for" loop. I was trying to set the field like this:

```
<%= file.field :asset, :image_url %>
```

Which would output something like:

```
<input type="file" name="asset[image_url]" />
```

So my question is:

Is there a way to get fields to change scope like "fields_for" does or do you have to use that loop for nested forms?

Comment: i think Form's not called "nested form" if it doesn't have `fields_for`. Why do you want to avoid using `fields_for`?

Comment: It seemed a bit overkill for one field and the parameters in the POST looked like it should work, but the SQL statement would send `nil` unless I was using `fields_for`

Comment: so please post your form with fields_for and your controller to create object. Maybe you used wrong `params[...]`

Comment: If you think its overkill, you can always just code the fields manually, or using tag helpers (text_field_tag, etc.).  And you can also write your own form handlers (see the simple_form gem, for example).  But the idea of "going with the flow" of Rails should become deeply embedded in your approach to writing Rails.  It's written to save you time and effort and results in beautifully consistent results.  If it works "the Rails way", you're done.